# How to prevent following view controller inheriting navigation view controller bar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app starts off with a navigation controller then, using segues, continues onto two view controllers followed by a tab bar controller.

The problem is that the tab bar controller still inherits the navigation bar at the top, and displays the back button. I don't want the user to be able to click the back button, but rather use a click a separate log-out button to return to the beginning.

Essentially, how can the views following the tab bar controller un-inherit the navigation bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

but it's not the right way to go , if the previous flow of vcs are not needed any more after the tab is presented you need to remove/clear ( for many reasons like improving performance in freeing memory of un needed vcs ) , by assigning

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = tabBar
```

instead of presenting/pushing it

Comment: So my code now looks like:             `let nameOfTabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nameOfTabBarController") as! nameOfTabBarController`
            
`(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = nameOfTabBarController` but the app crashes when changing between the two.

Comment: what crash log ??

Answer (score 0):

if incase , user can not come back to previous page unless logout after user goes to tabbar controller then better change root view controller of window .

if both are two different flow better handle with two navigation controller . 
example : signup / login flow  and actual business flow . go with two different navigation controllers